# Calculating flux of axisymmetric electric field through a sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

The following problem and its solution is taken from I. E. Irodov's book basic laws of electromagnetism :

[image: i.e. irodov's book basic laws of electromagnetism]
[image: Relevant figure]

I do not understand how the fact that field is axisymmetric leads to the conclusion that flux through sphere is same as the cylinder circumscribing it.

As charge inside cylinder is more than that in sphere , by gauss's law shouldn't it ( the flux)  be more?

I found another way to solve the problem - solving the integral $$ \oint E\cdot dS=\oint E*n*dS $$ where n is the normal vector for sphere that is $$n= \frac{(x\widehat{i} +y\widehat{j}+z\widehat{k})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$$ then the answer is same as in the book (this method was new to me , I found it on some russian site).

So it is correct. Hence I think I'm misinterpreting the argument in the book. Please help me understand it.

So as we know flux through cylinder = that through sphere , using gauss's law , that would imply that there is no net charge in the volume difference between sphere and cylinder. How is that possible?

Can someone tell me how the charge distribution in this case looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The electric field in the problem has no $z$ component, so it quite simple to calculate the flux through a cylinder with axis parallel to the $ z $ axis; then you choose a cylinder that contains the sphere you are interested in. Let $\Sigma$ be the surface of the cylinder, $ V $ its volume, $\Sigma '$ and $ V' $ the surface and volume of the sphere; by the divergence theorem:

$$ \int_{\Sigma} \mathbf{E} d\mathbf{S} = \int_{V} \text{div}(\mathbf{E})  dV $$

By the additivity of the integral:

$$ \int_{V} \text{div}(\mathbf{E})  dV = \int_{V'} \text{div}(\mathbf{E})  dV' + \int_{V''} \text{div}(\mathbf{E})  dV'' $$
where $V''$ is the region you obtain subtracting $V'$ from $ V$;

but on $ V'' $, $ \text{div}(\mathbf{E})=0$ since this region contains no charge; thus you get:

$$ \int_{\Sigma} \mathbf{E} d\mathbf{S} = \int_{V} \text{div}(\mathbf{E})  dV = \int_{V'} \text{div}(\mathbf{E})  dV =\int_{\Sigma '} \mathbf{E} d\mathbf{S} $$

and thus the flux through the cylinder it is equal to the flux through the sphere.

Comment: Why does V'' contain no charge? That is precisely what was bugging me.

Comment: @AGoogler The first time I read I understood the whole charge was contained in the sphere; actually it is not clear from the text.

Comment: The radius R is arbitrary so I don't think its only in the sphere. Further , if it were only in the sphere I don't think its formula would be like that in the question. Also the solution using integrals that i gave doesn't assume that yet gets the same answer.

Comment: @AGoogler In any case, the vector normal to the sphere surface is $ x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} + z \mathbf{k} $, while that normal to the lateral surface of the cylinder is $ x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} $; since the electric field has no $ z$ component, its internal product with those 2 vectors is the same and hence the flux.

Comment: So using gauss's law , that would imply that there is no net charge in the volume difference between sphere and cylinder. How is that possible?

Comment: @AGoogler No, no, it just means that the surface integrals of this particular electric field through the surface of that sphere and the lateral surface of that cylinder are equal. This is only due to the particular form of the electric field. Remember Gauss' law it is valid for the flux through a closed surface; in the case of the cylinder you are NOT considering a closed surface.

Comment: Using gauss's law , flux=charge inside/epsilon . If flux is same , shouldn't charge inside be same?

Comment: Remember Gauss' law it is valid for the flux through a closed surface; in the case of the cylinder you are NOT considering a closed surface.

Comment: You can consider the cylinder to be closed as anyway the flux through the up and down circles is zero (because E is parallel to the surface of those circles.)

Comment: mmm true. I guess it really means that there is no net charge in the volume between the sphere and cylinder.

Comment: That looks like a very weird charge distribution . There is no charge between any sphere with centre at origin and its corresponding cylinder. Is that even possible? By the way , thanks a lot!

Comment: The electric field itself it is weird so I guess the charge distribution will be too. You are welcome! I am studying the same topics and it has been an useful discussion!